# Lucene4 search not working

Tags: java, search, indexing, lucene

I am new to Lucene, using Lucene4. Trying to create index for a huge RDBMS table and do search from lucene index instead of table directly. Gathered bit and pieces from different sites, tried it out and indexing "seems" to be working ok. Following files are created in index directory: `_uu.fdt`, `_uu.fdx`, `_uu.fnm`, `_uu.si`, `segments.gen`, `segments_rs`.

Tried retrieve a record from stored index but it did not work. Hit is failing, hit count is returning zero.

Code snippet for creating index:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT product_id, product_name, brand_id, brand_name, price, screen_type, size_category, usage_category FROM mobile_product_master WHERE product_id like 'No0%'");
Directory storeIndexDirectory = FSDirectory.open(new File("E:\\index_dir"));
IndexWriterConfig indexWriterConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_40, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_40));

while(rs.next())
{
    productId = rs.getString("product_id");
    productName = rs.getString("product_name");
    brandId = rs.getString("brand_id");
    brandName = rs.getString("brand_name");
    price = rs.getString("price");
    screenType = rs.getString("screen_type");
    sizeCategory = rs.getString("size_category");
    usageCategory = rs.getString("usage_category");

    //doc = new Document(new Field());
    doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new Field("product_id",productId,Store.YES,Index.NO));
    doc.add(new Field("product_name",productName,Store.YES,Index.NO));
    doc.add(new Field("brand_id",brandId,Store.YES,Index.NO));
    doc.add(new Field("brand_name",brandName,Store.YES,Index.NO));
    doc.add(new Field("price",price,Store.YES,Index.NO));
    doc.add(new Field("screen_type",screenType,Store.YES,Index.NO));
    doc.add(new Field("size_category",sizeCategory,Store.YES,Index.NO));
    doc.add(new Field("usage_category",usageCategory,Store.YES,Index.NO));

    indexWriter = new IndexWriter(storeIndexDirectory, indexWriterConfig);
    indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
    indexWriter.close();
    doc = null;
}
```

Code snippet for search:

```
String queryString = arg[0];

Directory storeIndexDirectory = FSDirectory.open(new File("E:\\index_dir"));
IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.open(storeIndexDirectory);
IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);

QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_40,"product_id",new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_40));
Query query = parser.parse(queryString);

TopDocs topDocs = indexSearcher.search(query,1000);         
ScoreDoc[] hits = topDocs.scoreDocs;

System.out.println(hits.length);

for(int i=0;i < hits.length; i++)
{
    int docId = hits[i].doc;
    Document d = indexSearcher.doc(docId);
    System.out.println(d.get("product_id") + "," + d.get("product_name") + "," + d.get("brand_id") + "," + d.get("brand_name") + "," + d.get("price") + "," + d.get("screen_type") + "," + d.get("size_category") + "," + d.get("usage_category"));             
}
```

I am not able to locate the error in search or indexing part.

Comment: Any particular reason that you're not using the latest available version of Lucene?
It might help if you show some example rows and what you're using for input for search.

Comment: @user2861409 Does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks a lot srs, I am able to figure out the answer as soon as I posted the question. I used Index.ANALYZED instead of index.no. It worked out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: My bad I was working on another hectic schedule and I really really did not have time to visit the page again. Thanks again SRS......

Answer (score 1):

With Lucene if you want that your field is "searchable" you must create a field with **`Index.YES`**. 
In your example all `new Field(...)` statements have **`Index.NO`** parameter.
Change it to **`Index.YES`** only for a field you want to search.

You can also use [TextField](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/TextField.html) instead of generic Field with **`Index.YES`**.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved now. I used Index.ANALYZED while creating a field[adding to document] instead of using Index.NO. As SRS has pointed out, Index.YES would also work.
This raises a new question to me; In Lucene, I have to mark Index.YES/Index.ANALYZED to make the field searchable. So what is the case where someone would want a field to be created with searchable disabled? We use Lucene , store docs/fields to search it so in which use case do we use Index.No?!. Thanks.